# How to play mp3 with exo player

Tags: android, mp3, exoplayer

Please help me, the below code is not working:

```
    // 1. Instantiate the player.
    mPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(1);
    // 2. Construct renderer.
    Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(1024);
    DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(self, null, "userAgent");
    ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(Uri.parse(mSongObj.getUrl()), dataSource, allocator, 1 * 1024);
    MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource);

    // 3. Inject the renderer through prepare.
    mPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);

    // 4. Start playback.
    mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    // Don’t forget to release when done!
    mPlayer.release();
```

Many thanks

Comment: Never used ExoPlayer, but the last line `mPlayer.release();` seems like one of the possible reasons why your code doesn't work. Don't you find it weird releasing the player object you just asked to play a sound?

Comment: Thanks Roberto, but if i remove mPlayer.release() then i get this error:

Internal track renderer error.
                                                                         com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecUtil$DecoderQueryException: Failed to query underlying media codecs
                                                                             at com.google.android.exoplayer.SampleSourceTrackRenderer.doPrepare(SampleSourceTrackRenderer.java:78)

Comment: Roberto is right, calling mPlayer.release() will cancel your playback. Can you provide more details on the error from doPrepare() ? Stack trace, error details. Also, what device is this running on, and can you provide the mp3 file? Does this mp3 play on the same device in other apps?

Comment: @ChrisJ: I'm using LG LTE(4.1.2). The mp3 file is playing with MediaPlayer. As i told above, if i remove mPlayer.release() method then i get the error. :( any suggestions please.

Comment: @NaPro release() will cancel the playback. Can you provide more details on the error, or the mp3 file itself?

Comment: @ChrisJ: Here's the file: http://fruitysolution.vn:8888/mp3online-ilyas/upload/1448439796.mp3

Please view the log file, i can not comment here, it's too long.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwXx_cIz_HCtaVVzRG9CNlZTUU0/view?usp=sharing